# "There has been an error processing your request" but no /var/report directory

Tags: error, magento-1.9

I have 1.9.1 and finished building the site a few days ago. Nothing was ever wrong, now all of a sudden this morning I get an error on ALL pages frontend and admin:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 189535875249

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473705/there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request-error-log-record-number) and [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/57578/) but it seems this is for a different version of Magento as I do not have var/report. So I have no idea where to even check this specific error but from everywhere I can see I need to manually create a tmp folder and edit some core code. I guess some Magento developer decided havint the install create the correct directories was not important and the better solution was to crash people's frontend a few days after install with no warning.

Can anyone tell me where the var/report has been moved?

Comment: Please add some error log in the question, you can find file "189535875249" under "var/report" directory using FTP detail or look into "var/log" directory.

Comment: If you do not have a `var/report` then your `var/` isn't writeable by the webserver and that's very likely your exception problem to begin with. Investigate why suddenly var isn't writeable (the installer checks if it is).

Answer (score 5):

You can see the error in browser (if that's what you want to do) by renaming errors/local.xml.sample to errors/local.xml . The exceptions with traces will be shown in browser then.

Comment: Leaving this enabled on a live e-commerce server breaks PCI-DSS by displaying system stack-traces in plain view to anyone visiting the website.

Answer (score 3):

*it seems this is for a different version of Magento as I do not have var/report*

Missing var/report indicates that something is wrong with the file permissions in the var/ directory tree. You will not be able to view the files or find the folder because Magento is being prevented from creating it in the first place and therefore has no place to create the error stack trace file.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit]
Simply go to your var/report directory in your Magento installation root.
[/Edit]

If you want to find the specific error log file being generated by Magento, do the following:

```
$ sudo su -
$ cd /
$ find -name ((error_code))
```

For example,

```
find -name 1035788059901
```

Sample output:

```
./var/www/magento/var/report/1035788059901
```

Then

```
$ vim /var/www/magento/var/report/1035788059901
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the index.php file found in  the root of the project. In the file find the line that says:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

put the statement inside the if block outside of the block so that it is seen as:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    }
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

This should show you the error when you try to load the page in the browser.