# Redis Server restart options

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, redis

I have setup a redis server and I see a redis-server running in daemon mode. I thought the following stops the redis server

```
service redis-server stop
```

However, when i run that command, the website crashes and it throws up the below error
[image]

To avoid that I restart redis with

```
service redis-server start
```

or with

```
src/redis-server
```

I am not able to understand the difference between the above two restart options.

Also, why does the magento site go down when i stop the redis-server ?

Trying to get a hang of redis and any help/resources greatly appreciated. 
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to understand the difference between the above two restart options.

The first one is the *service* command of your operating system. The second one is the binary of the Redis daemon when you compile it from source.

You find the first command [documented with your operating system](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon). The second one is [documented with the Redis project](http://redis.io/download). Please relate to those resources for in-depth details.

> Also, why does the Magento site go down when I stop the redis-server ?

Because a component expected to work wasn't available. This exceptional situation must have caused an exception. [See the report (as numbered)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/25386/4115) and check the other logs for the exact error description. You could also [enable the developer mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15482/4115) but then take care if you're [debugging AJAX requests](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/62500/4115).

Comment: lot of good pointers in there. Thanks will check and revert

Comment: note, you canusually do sudo service redis-server **re**start